# Symfony/Doctrine deserialize time

Tags: symfony, serialization, time, doctrine

I have created the following field in my Doctrine entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="time")
 * @Groups({"default"})
 */
private $timeFrom;
```

I'm trying to deserialize my entity using the following code:

```
$workingDays = $serializer->deserialize($json, WorkingDay::class, 'json', array('groups' => array('default')));
```

I have tried several time/datetime formats from javascript, but Symfony seems to deserialize none of them.

My question is: What type of format does Symfony want as an input to deserialize to time?

Comment: Might seem obvious, but did you add the setter and getter for that property to your entity, since it's private ?

Comment: When you deserialize it, what happens? Null value, incorrect value?

Comment: It gives me an error. The property path constructor needs a string or an instance of "Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPath". Got: "integer. And yes, I've added getters and setters. That is not really my issue though. I just want to know what time format I have to put in my JSON.

Comment: How do you instantiate your `$serializer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of Serializer's docs, you need to include `DateTimeNormalizer` ([link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#normalizers)) when instantiating your `$serializer` instance.

```
$normalizers = [
    ...,
    new DateTimeNormalizer(),
];

$serializer = new Serializer(normalizers, [new JsonEncoder()]);
```

And, then, use the line from your question. In theory, it should work, but at the time I am not able to test it. Can you do it?

`DateTimeNormalizer` uses RFC3339 format, and according to it, this is an example of properly formatted value: `1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z`

## UPDATE:

In order to make it work, as I assumed above, you need to include `DateTimeNormalizer` in your serializer's normalizer list. However, this is where it gets tricky.

1. Order of normalizers is important:

You have to put `DateTimeNormalizer` first, otherwise, your will get funky misleading `MissingConstructorArgumentsException`.

2. Type discovery

Serializer needs to know how to get `string` denormalized into `DateTime`. To do that, `ObjectNormalizer` has a type-extractor which will be used to find more about underlying type. Type can be discovered in several ways, but I assume your will be done either via [`PhpDocExtractor`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_info.html#phpdocextractor) or [`DoctrineExtractor`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_info.html#doctrineextractor).

Now, the example:

```
// Prepare the data in form of JSON string
$incomingData = [
    'id' => 1337,
    'time' => '2018-07-24T01:29:50.00Z',
    'info' => 'Lorem ipsum'
];
$rawData = json_encode($incomingData);


$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));

// Very important to set type extractor
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, null, null, new PhpDocExtractor());

$normalizers = [
    new DateTimeNormalizer(),
    $normalizer,
];

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, [new JsonEncoder()]);

$myObject = $serializer->deserialize($rawData, FooObject::class, 'json');

var_dump($myObject);
```

This produced:

```
object(App\Data\FooObject)[3333]
  private 'id' => int 1337
  private 'time' => 
    object(DateTime)[3540]
      public 'date' => string '2018-04-12 23:20:50.520000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 2
      public 'timezone' => string 'Z' (length=1)
  private 'info' => string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11)
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'll give this a try tommorow! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error using this setup. What type of field does the serializer expect me to provide? Do I provide time like a datetime string? Or a different string like '08:00:00'. I've tried both but it gives me same error message.

Comment: Apologies, I haven't been around to test this. I am going to attempt to do this in couple of hours and update my answer..

Comment: Soo, this took me awhile to even try, but I managed to make it work. Updating the answer...